# How to access functions of a parent node module from the object of a child node module (or extended node module)?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Suppose there is an existing node module ParentModule and I create a ChildModule by extending ParentModule. I add more functions and properties to ChildModule.

During implementation, **How can I access the functions of ParentModule from the object of the ChildModule**?

ParentModule.js
- parentProperty-1
- parentProperty-2
.
.
.
- parentFunction-1
- parentFunction-2
- parentFunction-3
.
.
.
Exports = ParentModule

ChildModule.js
import ParentModule

```
- childProperty-A
- childProperty-B
.
- childFunction A
.
Exports = ChildModule
```

during implementation, I would like to use as **var cModule = require("ChildModule");**

So How can I access like this =>  **cModule.parentFunction-1()?**

Or

How do I achieve this **cModule.parentFunction-1()?**

Let me know if there is a work around?

Plz Note: I have not written any syntax above, its just for explanation.

Comment: There is no such thing as a parent or child module.  There are just modules.  A module exports things they want ANY other module to be able to access.  If you're finding that a module that gets imported wants access to things in the module that is importing it, then you either need to export a function that allows to pass in those things to the module or you need to restructure your code that the common things are in a third module that both can import.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this would be to have your child module export a function which takes in an as an argument a function that you can then call. So, as an example, let's make the `parentModule.js`:

```
function parentFunction() {
  console.log("This is the parent function!");
}

const cModule = require("cModule.js")(parentFunction);
```

`childModule.js`:

```
function childFunction(parentFunction) {
  console.log("This is the child function. I twill call the parent's function.");
  parentFunction();
}

module.exports = function(parentFunction) {
  return {
    childProperty1: childProperty1,
    childProperty2: childProperty2,
    childFunctionThatWantsTheParentFunction: () => childFunction(parentFunction)
  }
}
```

This is similar to the way that I like to populate Express routes and separate them out into their own files - I have route files that export a single function, and that function takes the `app` function that `Express()` creates. Example:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello!");
  });
}
```